# Dominator tree with edges annotated by min-cut size

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, minimum-cuts

Consider the dominator tree of, say, the graph of objects in memory, computed by a memory profiler - one of the most powerful memory leak debugging features, I believe.

The dominator tree tells you "if you manage to make this object unreachable, you'll reduce overall memory consumption by its whole subtree".

Obviously, the next question is "How do I make this object unreachable?", and the dominator tree gives only a partial answer to that: "by disconnecting it from this parent node which dominates over it".

Min-cuts would answer this remaining question ("how do I make this node unreachable from that node"). I already asked [a general question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25762/indexing-structure-for-all-pairs-min-cuts-in-a-huge-dag) about this and unfortunately it stayed unanswered, but I think it would be useful to, at least, produce a dominator tree where every parent-child edge would be annotated with the *size* of the minimum cut between them.

I'm wondering: is there an algorithm for efficiently computing a dominator tree annotated in this fashion?